.htaccess doesn't seem to be redirecting my file requests properly
I have a Svelte Node.js application (compiled with adapter-node) and WordPress installation in the /public_html folder. I've set the WordPress URL to be [domain].com/admin. My code structure looks a little bit like this:
public_html/
├─ admin/
│  ├─ all the wordpress files go here
│  ├─ ...
├─ app.js <-- entrypoint for the Svelte Node.js application
├─ build/ <-- Svelte compiled all my code into this folder
│  ├─ client/
│  │  ├─ script.js
│  │  ├─ style.css
│  │  ├─ ...
│  ├─ server/
│  │  ├─ index.js
│  │  ├─ ...
├─ .htaccess
├─ ...


The following is an abridged version of how my .htaccess file looks like minus all the rules automatically added by other WordPress plugins:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/_app/(.*)$ /build/client/_app/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>

What I am trying to achieve with the first part of my .htaccess file is: if request is a file and has /_app/ in the path, redirect it to /build/client/_app/$1 instead.
The second part should do: ignore all ^/admin/ requests (as they are WordPress related) and all file related requests. proxy all other requests to localhost:3000/$1.
Everything works perfectly when I access [domain].com–I can see the contents of the page and the links work fine. However, none of my scripts and style files are loading. They are all still going to /_app/ instead of being redirected to /build/client/_app/$1. I'm not sure why they aren't being redirected. Can someone help me out please?

For .htaccess rule, it should be: RewriteRule ^_app/(.*)$
